# Vue.js matching data value in table based on the row value or html id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I built a table with month and year as columns, this is fixed and can't be changed.

My table is currently generated to be like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody class="table">
        <tr>
            <td id="03-2019">03-2019</td>
            <td id="02-2019">02-2019</td>
            <td id="01-2019">01-2019</td>
            <td id="12-2018">12-2018</td>
            <td id="04-2017">04-2017</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "dynamicData">
            <td>10</td>
            <td>227</td>
            <td>342</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Table row with `id "dynamicData"` is generated by `v-for` model.

The data set i have is a map which has key as the month-year, and the value as the result.

So it looks like this:

```
var dataSet = {
  "12-2018 : "10",
  "03-2019" : "227",
  "04-2017": "342"
};
```

I generated my value as below with the `dataSet`:

```
tr.dynamicData
    td(v-for="data in dataSet") {{data}}
```

But this is NOT what I want. I want the data matches the date on the top row. For examle, under column `03-2019`, the data value should be `227`, under column `02-2019`, the value should be empty since in my `dataSet` there is not value for date `02-2019`.

How can I achieve this with vue? I tried to create a function but seems `v-for` converted my map into an array.

Comment: 1. Add the first table row's months as array to your app 2. create a 2nd five element array based on the months and `dataSet` (using `null` or `"-"` for empty cells) 3. output both rows using `v-for` loops.

Comment: @ChrisG can you please add it to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to grab the dates from the first row in a way that makes sense to your app (I don't know if that data is rendered by a BE, if it's hardcoded or where it comes from).

```
let dates = ['03-2019','02-2019','01-2019','12-2018','04-2017'];
```

These dates will be used as the keys to find their corresponding values.

Now iterate through those dates and grab their corresponding values in the data set:

```
let dynamicData = dates.map( date => this.dataSet[date] )
  return dynamicDates;
}
```

Finally, in your v-for do the same you're doing but use the new dynamicData variable instead

```
tr.dynamicData
  td(v-for="data in dataSet") {{data}}
```

Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/jaireina/pen/MRzoxQ) I did with this to test.

Depending on how you can get the data of the first row, you could use dynaicData as a computed variable. It will be the same except that the code will be a little bit cleaner.

Good luck